# How do I use the appProperties with the ruby api-client

Tags: google-api-ruby-client

I can't determine how to add custom properties or search for them.

Everything I have tried is giving me a `Error - #<Google::Apis::ClientError: invalid: Invalid query>` when I attempt to search for them. I can successfully complete other queries but I don't know if the client is setup to work with appProperties (or even properties at all).

Basically I just need the correct syntax for searching and adding since it doesn't appear to be in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a reference to an authorized DriveService, you can search based on appProperties using a q-parameter (documented [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)), like this:

```ruby
file_list = drive.list_files(
  q: "appProperties has { key='my_app_key' and value='my_val' }",
  fields: 'files(id, name, appProperties)',
  spaces: 'drive')
```

If you omit the `fields` parameter then the search will still work but the properties themselves won't be returned.

Updating appProperties is definitely arcane and the documentation is opaque. What you need is the ID of the file, and a File value object as a container for the attributes to update. Something like this:

```ruby
new_app_properties = { 'my_app_key' => 'my_val' }
update_f = Google::Apis::DriveV3::File.new(app_properties: new_app_properties)
drive.update_file(file_id, update_f)
```